# Sine Oscillator - for audio frequency

Tags: oscillator, wave

I'm looking to create several sine waves on a single circuit. All must be under 20Khz frequency and each must be unique. Mostly it will be 5-10 frequencies needed.

As I found - almost all crystal oscillator are in Mhz frequencies and only one kind is 32Khz (which is still too high).

I should be able to get this wave on the other side using FFT.

Ideas? :)

Thanks

Comment: How about the expected spectral purity of each sine wave? That parameter could lead to different solutions.

Comment: Do you want the frequencies to be fixed or adjustable?

Comment: What's important to you?  Frequency stability?  Frequency accuracy?  (5.000000 kHz)  Signal to noise ratio?  Distortion?  Are you doing [multitone testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_quality_measurement#Multitone_testing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easilly divide the 32KHz crystal frequency with a Binary Counter (such as the [4040](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/HEF4040B.pdf)) to give 16KHz, 8KHz, 4KHz, 2KHz, 1KHz, 500Hz, etc...

Then some clever filtering can create a sine(ish) wave from each of those square waves.

Comment: Then you can better start from a **12MHz crystal**. Very common value, and many more dividers. These are the first multiples of 1kHz you can get from 12MHz: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 20, 24, 25, 30, 32, 40, 48, 50, 60, 75, 80, 96, 100,...

Comment: Also, a 32kHz crystal is actually 32.768kHz, so you don't get the nicely round numbers from your answer.

Comment: You get nice round *binary* numbers ;)  16,384Hz, 8,192Hz, 4,096Hz, 2,048Hz, 1,024Hz, 512Hz...

Comment: Yes, but for frequencies binary doesn't make sense like it does in addressing, for instance. Note that most of the time the 32.768kHz is just used to get a 1Hz signal. (yes, I noticed the smiley!)

Comment: I have often wondered why it's 32,767Hz they use.  I guess it's easy to divide right down to 1Hz through binary means.  But why not start with a lower frequency?

Comment: Lower frequencies mean larger crystals, which cost more, but also require more power. The 32kHz crystals use a special construction (tuning-fork) to be able to make them so small. And it's indeed because it require so little hardware to divide down to 1Hz.

Comment: That sound perfect! Do you have any examples on how this can be accomplished? (some circuit examples) - I come from the CS background and not electronics, so complicated stuff is little hard on me for now. Many thanks :)

Comment: @roman - What Matt didn't tell you is that it's not that easy to filter out a sine from a square wave, especially not when it has to be done for multiple frequencies. I'm going to leave this to him to answer :-). (The DDS would have created a nice sine)

Comment: @stevenvh Gee, thanks.  It's more likely Olin will be able to answer that part of it sensibly.

Comment: @Matt - Oh no, that won't do, *you* got paid for it! ;-)

Comment: @Stevenvh I did?  Then where did the cash go?!

Comment: @Matt - [here!](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/4245/matt-jenkins?tab=reputation)

Comment: @stevenvh Can I withdraw some and buy a solder rework station?

Answer (score 6):

Similar questions were asked [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16512/is-this-a-suitable-sine-wave-osc-how-would-i-control-the-frequency) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/whats-the-easiest-cheapest-variable-frequency-sine-wave-oscillator).

In [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16512/is-this-a-suitable-sine-wave-osc-how-would-i-control-the-frequency/16525#16525) I talk about **DDS**, direct digital synthesis, which has replaced classical analog oscillators like **Wien bridge**. The DDS technique is crystal-based so has the same stability and accuracy.
[Here](http://www.myplace.nu/avr/minidds/index.htm) you'll find a design for a simple DDS. DDSs which use [special function ICs](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD9835.pdf) typically achieve a wide frequency range with very high frequency resolution.

Comment: Sadly, your link for the simple DDS design is dead :(